# 1 second difference between boost microsec_clock and second_clock::universal_time

Tags: c++, boost

While working on a module that writes incoming events with a timestamp to a file, I encountered a problem to which I can't find any information on the www. Hopefully some of you can help me:

part of the code:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime micro_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
std::cout << "micro time: " << micro_time  << std::endl;

boost::posix_time::ptime utc_time(boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time());
std::cout << "utc time: " << utc_time << std::endl;
```

It works quite fine, but then there is a mismatch by 1 second between the two timestamps. These 4 events occur right after each other, but with event 3 there is something wrong. But right after it, everything is fine again.

```
1. event (good):  
micro time: 2012-May-11 13:13:32.002949  
utc time:   2012-May-11 11:13:32.003069

2. event (good):  
micro time: 2012-May-11 13:13:32.003600  
utc time:   2012-May-11 11:13:32.003716  

3. event (bad):   
micro time: 2012-May-11 13:13:32.004241  
utc time:   2012-May-11 11:13:33.004411  

4. event (good again):  
micro time: 2012-May-11 13:13:32.004943  
utc time:   2012-May-11 11:13:32.005073
```

I'm using a 32bit Kubuntu and boost libary 1.46. Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing the mismatch?

Comment: Surely a 1 second clock is always likely to be out by 1s when compared to a microsecond clock? Or am I misunderstanding the question here...?

Comment: The workaround in your case is obviously to make sure to work with 1 clock.  Still, it is an interesting question, maybe more as feedback on boost (http://www.boost.org/support/bugs.html)

Comment: Is it reproducible? If not, it might have been a short performance fluctuation caused by (an)other process(es). But typically, you'd use only one clock if you are about to measure the same point time, just to prevent bugs like this.

Comment: As the saying goes, "a person with a clock always knows what time it is; a person with two clocks is never sure."

Comment: They boil down to different CRT functions, which are probably return inconsistent results on your platform.